# First-Order Logic Converse True?

Tags: first-order-logic

I really cannot find a good title for this question. In [NLTK Chapter 10](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html) Section 3.1 (last part), there is this paragraph:

**1**. An occurrence of a variable $x$ in a formula $\phi$ is free in $\phi$ if that occurrence doesn't fall within the scope of `all x` or `some x` in $\phi$.

**2**. Conversely, if $x$ is free in formula $\phi$, then it is bound in `all x`.$\phi$ and `exists x`.$\phi$.

**3**. If all variable occurrences in a formula are bound, the formula is said to be closed.

I understand sentence **1**. That means in some formula `((all x. cat(x)) -> meow(x))`, the second occurrence of `x` is unbounded. However, how does **2** make sense? Let's say there is some formula `((exists y. milk(y)) -> white(y))`. How do you prove **2**? `y` in `white(y)` is considered free in $\phi$ **but is not bound** in `exists y.milk(y)`.

Comment: 2 is a consequence of 1. In $(x=y)$ the occurrence of $x$ is *free*, because there is no quantifier whose *scope* include the said occurrence. If we put a quantifier $\forall x$ in front of the formula $\phi$ (like $(x=y)$), then the scope of the quantifier will be the complete formula $\phi$, and thus all occurrence of $x$ in it become *bound* by the quantifier.

Comment: And a variable, like $y$ in your example, may have both free occurrences and bound ones in the same formula.

Comment: yes, @MauroALLEGRANZA what you said makes sense. Today is Day 1 in understanding this and your explanation is very helpful.